# ADB over WiFi connection lost after restarting laptop

Tags: debugging, windows-10, adb, wifi, restart

**Devices** : I have a Windows 10 Laptop and Redmi Note 5 Pro mobile device.

**Steps to follow:**

1: Run "adb devices" on cmd.
2: Found my device
3: Run "adb tcpip 5555"
4: Run "adb connect "
5: Now my device is connected over adb. I can debug normally over wifi
6:  On restarting  my Laptop i Lose adb connection....

So i have to recconnect to the device every single time i restart my laptop by following the first 5 steps. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: what you describe is prety normal and adb does not support any kind of persistent connection which would survive reboots. But mobile device remembers tcp configuration until it reboots. So when laptop reboots it is enough to run ```adb connect <phone_ip>``` only. You can reserve permanent IP address for specific mobile device at router (or local network dhcp server) so you could make simple bat file and invoke it via autorun. And use another bat file to configure everything when mobile device is not configured and is attached via usb.

Comment: Thanks alot. I started using  adb connect <phone_ip> everytime i restart windows !.